# Send Some Form Of Notification When An Asp.net Windows Form Is Submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have an`asp.net` web form which on click of a button shows a modal with 3 fields and a submit button.

All i want is for some sort of notification to be sent to me with the details of the form.

The thing is, is that my application sits on our 'DEV' environment and i was thinking of an email being sent to my email address in our 'Live' environment so it will need to be done via Microsoft Outlook but i cant figure out how to do this at all.

I have done this in the past using 'Hotmail' but i cant figure out or get the email to be sent to me at all.

I have tried the following

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

protected void BtnSuggestPlace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress("antonydev@dev1.test.com");

    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("antony@test.co.uk"));
    message.Subject = "This is my subject";
    message.Body = "This is the content";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    client.Send(message);
}
```

and i have also tried the code i use for the hotmail

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

protected void BtnSuggestPlace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                //Creates the email object to be sent
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

                //Adds your email address to the recipients
                msg.To.Add("antony@test.co.uk");

                //Configures the address you are sending the email from
                MailAddress address = new MailAddress("antonydev@dev1.test.com");
                msg.From = address;

                //Allows HTML to be used when setting up the email body
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //Email subjects title
                msg.Subject = "Place Suggestion";

                msg.Body = "<b>" + lblPlace.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldPlace.ToString()
                           + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                           "<b>" + lblLocation.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldLocation.ToString()
                            + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                           "<b>" + lblName.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldName.ToString();

                //Configures the SmtpClient to send the mail
**NOT TO SURE IF REQUIRED OR NOT**
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
                    client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if the provider requires it

                    //Setup credentials to login to the sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
**NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE AS PASSWORDS EXPIRE EVERY 28DAYS**
                        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("antonydev@dev1.testcom", "CurrentPassword");
                        client.Credentials = credentials;

                    //Send the email
                    client.Send(msg);

                // Create a Outlook Application and connect to outlook 
                Application OutlookApplication = new Application();

                // create the MailItem which we want to send 
                MailItem email = (MailItem)OutlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
                // Add a recipient for the email
                email.Recipients.Add("antonydev@dev1.test.com");
                // add subject and body of the email
                email.Subject = "Test";
                email.Body = "This is a test email to check outlook email sending code";

                //send email
                email.Send();
}
```

all i need is something passes what was entered to me but not sure how or what way to do it

**Update**

I have decided to setup a new gmail acc and use that but it always drops into my `catch` i suspect it's timing out can anyone help please.

The InnerException Message is:

*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.67.109:587*

```
protected void BtnSuggestPlace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region Email
    try
    {
        //Creates the email object to be sent
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        //Adds your email address to the recipients
        msg.To.Add("antony@test.co.uk");

        //Configures the address you are sending the email from
        MailAddress address = new MailAddress("NewGmailEmailAddress@gmail.com");
        msg.From = address;

        //Allows HTML to be used when setting up the email body
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //Email subjects title
        msg.Subject = "Place Suggestion";

        msg.Body = "<b>" + lblPlace.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldPlace.Text
                   + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                   "<b>" + lblLocation.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldLocation.Text
                    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                   "<b>" + lblName.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldName.Text;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("XXXusername", "MyPassword");//username doesn't include @gmail.com
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = nc;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Port = 587;

        //Send the email
        client.Send(msg);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Lets the user know if the email has failed
        lblNotSent.Text = "<div class=\"row\">" + "<div class=\"col-sm-12\">" + "There was a problem sending your suggestion. Please try again." + "</div>" + "</div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-sm-12\">" + "If the error persists, please contact Antony." + "</div>" + "</div>";
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What is the Exception?

Comment: @Lorek Added the innerexception message to the post

Comment: Can you ping smtp.gmail.com and see what IP address you get? It resolves to 74.125.22.108 for me.  The host name I get is gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.  Also, maybe SMTP is blocked on your network. And, FYI, you should try to make your example more compact. In the future, reduce your code as much as possible so that you have just enough to reproduce the problem. That makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Lorek It might be that its blocked as when i ping it, it comes back as "Request timed out" looks like i need to find another way of advising me someone has submitted something on the form as i have read the to use Outlook, it has to be open to send emails, which isn't great.  I need some way of knowing if a form has been submitted and an email was the best one i could think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the firewall is blocking it so the issue is not with the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use to send SMTP mail using a gmail account:

```
    public static void Send(string subject, string message, params string[] recipients)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential([YourAccountName], [YourAccountPassword]);//username doesn't include @gmail.com
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = nc;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Port = 587;
        try
        {
            string recipientString = string.Join(",", recipients);
            client.SendAsync([YourAccountName] + "@gmail.com", recipientString, subject, message, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Report(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added the code i am using for my gmail acc i have just set up but it always drops into my `catch`. Please see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

`173.194.67.109` is a valid gmail IP: don't specify port in order to estabilish an smtp connection with `SSL` (`587` is the `TLS` port).

I also recommend using `web.config` to store smtp settings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="enableSSL" value="true"/>
</appSettings>

<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="yourgmail@gmail.com">
            <network
                 host="smtp.gmail.com"
                 userName="yourgmail@gmail.com"
                 password="YourPassword" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

So your code could be something like this:

```
Dim email As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
email.Body = "YourBody"
email.Subject = "YourSubject"
email.To.Add("yourrecipient@email.com")

Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
smtp.EnableSsl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("enableSSL")
smtp.Send(email)
```